# How to simulate multiple fields in a terms query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have some code already written (java/spring) which allows users to select check boxes and then builds an elasticSearch query.  Up to now this has been working well as the requirement has been that terms in different categories should be AND queries and so it has been possible to loop through the tiered selection boxes building a terms match (OR queries) then combine them to and build a boolean terms query along these lines

```
{
 "bool" : {
   "must" : [ {
     "terms" : {
       "field1" : [ "term1", "term2" ]
     }
   }, {
     "terms" : {
       "field2" : [ "term3" ]
     }
   } ]
 }
```

There has been a new requirement to make some of the top level boxes OR queries so in these cases I would need something along the lines of

```
{
 "query": {
   "bool" : {
     "must" : {
       "terms" : { "field1" : ["term1"] , "field1" : ["term2"] } 
    }
   }
 }
```

}

This is not possible I assume (elasticSearch 2.4.1) as I get an error

```
"type": "query_parsing_exception",
"reason": "[terms] query does not support multiple fields",...
```

I'm guessing I should move this to a filter query but I wondered if anyone could confirm that this is the simplest most effective change (at this stage I'm looking for the path of least change) ?

Comment: Why not simply changing `must` to `should` in the first query?

Comment: Ouch that was easy, I even had the right page open, I'd just glossed over it being a bit nervous if the term should!  If you put that in an answer I can accept or if it's too simple for the forum I can delete, as you like...  (thanks by the way)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The solution is simply to use a `should` instead of a `must` in your first query:

```
{
 "bool" : {
   "should" : [ {                    <---- change this
     "terms" : {
       "field1" : [ "term1", "term2" ]
     }
   }, {
     "terms" : {
       "field2" : [ "term3" ]
     }
   } ]
 }
```

Comment: Val, can you explain why you choose `should` here instead of `must` as OP had?

Comment: @JBone because the OP needed an OR query

Comment: ha, I lost that part from the OP description. I should have paid more attention. thanks for clarifying

Comment: @JBone Yeah I had the same issue. The title of the question and the description are 2 separate things.

Answer (score 6):

Try with this :-

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                    "term": {
                        "field1": "1"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "field12": "1"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is still an AND query though.  Using Should as Val commented is the answer I think...  Thanks for the suggestion though